# Can "nothing" be a direct object?

Tags: pronouns, negation, direct-objects

In the sentence: "The boy kicked the ball," the *ball* is obviously the direct object.
A student asked me if the sentence were changed to "The boy kicked nothing," is *nothing* also a direct object?

Comment: Yes, *nothing* is a direct object. Both *ball* and *nothing* are nouns.

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't sure if the boy had to actually kick soemthing.

Comment: *Something* would also be a direct object.

Comment: I think it's beyond the mandate of this forum to decide whether "nothing" is actually "something" :)

Comment: @PhilMJones It should come as no surprise that [it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set)

Comment: You might profit from looking up _thematic relations_ at say Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

> - The boy kicked nothing

A good test for objects is to see whether the phrase can become the subject in a passivised version of the sentence. For the Original Poster's example we get the following sentence:

- Nothing was kicked by the boy.

Here we see *nothing* in subject position. We can do another little test just to check if this is the subject. If we make a question, does this word change places with the auxiliary verb *was*:

- Was nothing kicked by the boy?

Yes, *nothing* and *was* changed positions here. *Nothing* is definitely the subject of the passive voice sentence. This shows that it was the object in the active voice sentence.

Comment: Great tests.  It's also something to show the students so they can use them in the future.

Comment: They're by no means infallible. All had a good time. A good time was had by all. // All had their own teeth. *Their own teeth were had by all. There are articles here mentioning some direct-object look-alikes (He seemed a nice man / He walked a mile ...).

Answer (score 1):

A direct object that is a noun can be replaced by a pronoun.

- I like my teacher. I like him.

It can even be replaced by indefinite pronouns such as something, nothing, 
everything etc.

- I understand the text. I understand it. I understand everything/nothing.

Probably you wouldn't have doubts whether nothing can be a direct object if it were spelled as two words: I understand "no thing".